Collect PowerAPP not working, i can't show this in gallery
Good morning everyone! Collect PowerAPP not working
I'm trying to create a collection in powerAPP, but for some reason the Collect table doesn't seem to be connected to a gallery.
For example, I put in this code
Collect(col_fre; {name: “test”; age: “test”})

On a button in the onSelect function, and the col_fre table should appear to be connected to a gallery, but it doesn't.
I've tried everything (the documentation seems to be out of date). If anyone can help me, I'd be very grateful.
I tried to read the documentation, but it's out of date.

you need to add the col_fre as the items property for you Gallery. did you do this? also, you need to check that the gallery is actually displaying the related fields (name & Age) and not any other fields

Felipe, select your gallery and set it's items property to your collection col_fre.
Also are you getting any syntax error? I noticed you are using ; instead of ,
So please adjust your code as per your Power Apps language.
See below screen shots for clear understanding.
This below screen shot is showing OnSelect property of push button to create collection and insert initial value in it

Gallery Items property set to your collection, so if there are values in collection it will be displayed, run your app and see the results.

